# how to properly assign fields in subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

I am writing a project in Angular, but it seems to me that my problem is not related to this.
I am sending requests sequentially and trying to assign the response values ​​to a double array `private labels: any [][] = [[]];`.

```
getInfo(url: string, command: string, accessToken: string, companyToken: string, size: number) {
    return this.httpClient.post(url,
        JSON.stringify({
            'cmd': 'getInfo',
            'command': command,
            'date': this.getDate(),
            'accessToken': accessToken,
            'companyToken': companyToken,
            'size': size
        })
    );
}

  getData() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.commands.length; i++) {
        let labelsArr: string[] = [];
        let dataArr: string[] = [];
        this.getInfo(this.url, this.commands[i], this.accessToken, this.companyToken, 12)
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(response).length; j++) {
                            labelsArr[j] = Object.entries(response)[j][1][0];
                            dataArr[j] = Object.entries(response)[j][1][1];
                    }
                    this.labels[i] = labelsArr;
                    //not empty
                    console.log(this.labels);

                    this.AllData[i] = dataArr;
                });
    }
    //empty
    console.log(this.labels);

}
```

In getData() I output the resulting array, the fact is that it is not empty when outputting to `subscribe`, but if I try to display the value of the field outside `subscribe`, it turns out that the array is empty, I don't understand what this is connected with, can someone suggest?

P.S

I think this is due to the fact that the responses come later than I have time to use labels, how can I make them synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the subscribe callback is executed asynchronously after `console.log(this.labels)` in `getData()`. If you need to use `this.labels` after all the `getInfo()` requests you need to do it asynchronously. Use `forkJoin` to join all the getInfo() Observables:

```ts
    getData() {
      const observables = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.commands.length; i++) {
          observables.push(this.getInfo(this.url, this.commands[i], this.accessToken, this.companyToken, 12));
      }
      forkJoin(observables).subscribe(responses => {
        for(response of responses) {
          let labelsArr: string[] = [];
          let dataArr: string[] = [];
          for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(response).length; j++) {
            labelsArr[j] = Object.entries(response)[j][1][0];
            dataArr[j] = Object.entries(response)[j][1][1];
          }
          this.labels[i] = labelsArr;
          this.AllData[i] = dataArr;
        }
      });
    }
```

There are alternatives, like mapping every observable in its own pipe and then joining them. Also, `getInfo()` should return a typed object so you don't need to use `Object.keys`.

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that the responses come later than I have time to use labels, how can I make them synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

ok it worked

```
async getData() {

    for (let i = 0; i < this.commands.length; i++) {
        let labelsArr: string[] = [];
        let dataArr: string[] = [];
        await this.getInfo(this.url, this.commands[i], this.accessToken, this.companyToken, 12)
            .toPromise().then(
                response => {
                    for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(response).length; j++) {
                            labelsArr[j] = Object.entries(response)[j][1][0];
                            dataArr[j] = Object.entries(response)[j][1][1];
                    }
                    this.labels[i] = labelsArr;
                    this.AllData[i] = dataArr;
                });
    }
    //
   console.log(this.labels);

}
```

Comment: This solution will send the requests sequentially. You could use Promise.all() to send them out in parallel and continue after all have finished.